# How to import both xls and xlsx files using java in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring-mvc, apache-poi, xssf, hssf

In this method i used xssf class which is used to read xlsx file but we cant do it for xls file.for xls we need to have Hssf class  .User can import any format there .My requirement,Is there any Class that can be used instead of xssf and hssf to read both kind of file. in my example i used xssf.

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/import",method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public ModelAndView imports(Model model, @RequestParam("excelFile") MultipartFile excelfile){
        try {
            List<DepartmentModel> lstUser = new ArrayList<>();
            int i = 0;

            XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelfile.getInputStream());

            XSSFSheet worksheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
            while (i <= worksheet.getLastRowNum()) {

                DepartmentModel user = new DepartmentModel();

                XSSFRow row = worksheet.getRow(i++);
user.setHrName(row.getCell(0).getStringCellValue());
user.setDepartmentName(row.getCell(1).getStringCellValue());
user.setParentDepartment(row.getCell(2).getStringCellValue());


                lstUser.add(user);

            }

            departmentService.updateList(lstUser);

            model.addAttribute("lstUser", lstUser);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/listOfDepartment");
    }
```

Im having another method which i used Hssf to read xls file.But iam having only one import button user can upload any type of file xls,xlsx but for import button i can have one action eigther go to xssf or hssf method.So i like to know is there any possible way to have botth in single method.Or any other super class to having property of both Xssf and Hssf Class.

Comment: What have you tried? What do you mean with _both in the same method_? Please show some code to illustrate what the problem is.

Comment: first of  all Thanks for   rating my question

Comment: No offense @Ajai, but it's not a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, no
[minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If I understand, what you mean to ask is "what is the common supertype of HSSFWorkbook and XSSFWorkbook"? The answer is: Workbook - the rest is left as an exercise to the reader :-)

Comment: Sorry i do no how to explain. Thanks for your answer can you suggest me a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For supporting both `HSSF` as well as `XSSF` for reading and rewriting `*.xls` and `*.xlsx`, you will using [WorkbookFactory](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html) for creating [Workbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html). This is able creating `Workbook` from `InputStream` of `*.xls` as well as of `*.xlsx` files.

```
 FileInputStream fileinputstream = new FileInputStream("pathToExcelFile.xls_or_.xlsx");
 Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(fileinputstream);
```

Then, as long as possible, you will working with the interfaces of [Package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/package-summary.html) instead of the special `HSSF` or `XSSF` classes.

This is not always possible since `apache poi` is in development until now. But if not possible you can detect via `instanceof` what object (`HSSF` or `XSSF`)  you really are working with.

And for writing you will using the appropriate methods dependent of the `instanceof` the `Workbook`.

```
  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) {
   workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("pathToExcelFile.xlsx"));
  } else if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) {
   workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("pathToExcelFile.xls"));
  }
  workbook.close();
```

Up to `apache poi 3.17` `Workbook.write` has closed the `OutputStream`. Now in `apache poi 4.0.*` versions it not more closes the `OutputStream`. So we need using

```
  FileOutputStream out = null;
  if (workbook instanceof XSSFWorkbook) out = new FileOutputStream("pathToExcelFile.xlsx");
  else if (workbook instanceof HSSFWorkbook) out = new FileOutputStream("pathToExcelFile.xls");
  if (out != null) {
   workbook.write(out);
   out.close();
  }
  workbook.close();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i will try this code and tell..  :-)