# Check if Excel file supports Apache POI HSSF or XSSF

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI HSSF/XSSF library to support Excel file reading functionality in my java code.

Now we are struggling with a thing that, we are not sure which version of Excel we will receive. It can be very old one or new one with macros and so on.

```
Workbook worbook = null;
if(FileUtils.getFileExt(file).equalsIgnoreCase("xls")) {
    workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
} else if (FileUtils.getFileExt(file).equalsIgnoreCase("xlsx"))             
    workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream(file));
}
```

According to the Excel doc there is more formats like `xlsm`. `xlt` which we can receive.

Is there any other option to recognize which implementation should I use (HSSF vs XSSF)? Is there any possibility that `xls` will be not supported by HSSF?

Comment: If the first two bytes of the file are "PK" then it is in zip format, so `.xlsx` actually, `XSSFWorkbook`. It indeed is a version nightmare. Maybe one could LibreOffice let them be converted to a new `.xlsx`.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48751043/how-to-import-both-xls-and-xlsx-files-using-java-in-spring-mvc/48759496#48759496

Comment: @AxelRichter I saw. You can see even same code. However my problem is not to recognize by file extension. I am looking for other option and that was my question.

Comment: No, you haven't read my answer correctly. `WorkbookFactory` determines from file content what kind of `Workbook` (`HSSF` or `XSSF`) it must create.

Comment: Oh i really missed that first part somehow. My bad! Kudos for you!

Comment: Why not just use `WorkbookFactory` and let Apache POI figure it out for you?